# What happens if a company/individual conducts business with a sanctioned (embargoed) country when the sanction is not from their country?

Tags: trade, sanctions

Let's say that country A is under economic sanction (embargo) from country B, and country C is a key ally of country B. What happens if a company/individual from country C does business with country A?

An example would be a company based in the Dominican Republic who want to export goods to Cuba.

Can the Dominican Republic legally stop the company/individual from doing business? If so, which law they will use?

Cuban come to the Dominican Republic and Haiti very often to buy goods(mostly clothes) to resell, they strip the tags, maybe because of legal issues in Cuba.

But what if I import the good(basic necessities, clothing and apparels, no electronics) directly to them without them needing to come in DR just to get it.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about that business, or about wider geopolitics?

Comment: This question can use some more details about what you are asking. There is going to be a difference from selling in the sanctioned country itself and citizens of that country buying locally from a store.

Comment: I edited it, it's more like import good to a sanctioned country, I merely talk about the fact that they come buy in DR just to make a point, that's there is a need.

Comment: This question needs a lot more details now. Your answer is going to depend directly on what type of goods you are talking about. If you are talking about basic and simple food they might look away however if you are talking about advanced technology or luxury goods they might not. Something like weapons or military hardware are likely to get swift action taken. This is of course not taking into account they quantity of goods as it might not ever get noticed if it is small enough.

Comment: I modified it, just basic stuff like clothing and apparel

Comment: In the case of Cuba, look into the Helms Burton Act which bans the ship that docked in Cuba from entering a US port for, IIRC, 10 years, which in many cases would bankrupt a company, for the US is the largest trading country in the world.  Hence, very few ships dock in Cuba, which reinforces the illegal economic blockade on Cuba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

- **Either** C has enough influence in B to make B drop the matter,
- **or** B has enough influence in C to make C enact similar sanctions,
- **or** B sancions an entity in C, weakening the alliance,
- **or** B accepts that the sanctions are less than perfect.

This tends to be significant mostly when **B is the United States**, since most other countries realize that their global influence is limited and accept that their own sanctions are not universal.

A good recent example is [Nord Stream II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Stream), where Germany made the US accept a face-saving compromise. (Personally I think the US made a gross mistake in the official justification of their sanctions. The new pipeline endangers Eastern European countries like the Ukraine by allowing Russia to cut them off *while still supplying Western Europe*. That's arguably a bad thing for Europe, but the US claim that European dependence on Russian gas would grow was just plain wrong. The existing pipeline net *already* allows Russia to sell the gas to Europe that Europe needs. That, and the suspicion that the Trump administration wanted to sell American LNG, made Germany dig in and pull it through.)

Comment: Thanks, but I had another case in mind. Updated my question

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass, that might come down to my second and third bullet points. Does the Dominican Republic value their relations with the US so much that they go along, or do they defy the US?

Comment: Let's say the do have strong tie to US, but a private company/individual want to make business.

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass, then the US government would ask the Dominican government to ban this business. The Dominican government considers if it should follow that *request*. And the company would also face the possibility of being banned from doing business in the US, which is a strong deterrent.